# Importing a custom mongoose schema in another schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My software has a mongoose Schema, let's call it `carSchema`, and I am exporting a model of the `carSchema` called `Car`. Example:

```
/* Car.js */
var carSchema= new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    type: String,
    wheels: Number
});

carSchema.statics.drive = async function(){
    ...
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);
```

Now say my software has another schema called `lotSchema` in another file, that uses carSchema in it:

```
/* Lot.js */
var lotSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    carArr: [carSchema]
});

lotSchema.statics.getAllId = async function(){
    return carSchema[0]['_id']
}
```

How can I properly import or export `carSchema` for use in `lotSchema`? Would a simple `const carSchema = require('Car.js')` suffice?

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using not using es6/7 then you can do this

```
 /* Car.js */
    const carSchema= new Schema({
        _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        type: String,
        wheels: Number
    });

    carSchema.statics.drive = async function(){
        ...
    }
    module.exports.carSchema = carSchema;

    module.exports.carModel = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);





 /* Lot.js */
    const { carSchema , carModel } = require('./Car.js');
    var lotSchema = new Schema({
        _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        carArr: [carSchema]
    });

    lotSchema.statics.getAllId = async function(){
        return carSchema[0]['_id']
    }
```

Comment: Ah, so elsewhere if I only needed the carModel, could I just do `const { carModel } = require('./Car.js)` ?

Comment: @albert yes that is correct if you don't need the schema you don't need to import it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

> Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified
>   paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s). We
>   may populate a single document, multiple documents, plain object,
>   multiple plain objects, or all objects returned from a query.

Example:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const carSchema= new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    type: String,
    wheels: Number
});

const lotSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    cars: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Car' }]
});

mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);
mongoose.model('Lot', lotSchema);
```

Now, to populate works, you first need to create a car object `car = new Car({})` and a lot object `lot = new Lot({})`, and then:

```
lot.cars.push(car);
lot.save(callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in Car.js

```
module.exports = {
  useCarSchema: function(myCollection) {
    return mongoose.model('Car', carSchema, myCollection);
  }
}
```

And this in Lot.js

```
var carSchema     = require('./Car.js');
var Car =  carSchema.useCarSchema(myCollection);
```

Comment: Would this be any different than `module.export = mongoose.model('Car', carSchema)` and `var Car = require('./Car.js')`?

Comment: If you were only wanting to export `mongoose.model('Car', carSchema);` and nothing else, I suppose there wouldn't be a difference. I was thinking of a way that allowed you to export multiple functions, which you may or may not want to do at some point.

Comment: What if I were to write those functions as static methods of the schema, i.e. `carSchema.static.drive = function(){...}`. That export/require of that carSchema would technically still be able to use that function right? Or is this bad practice?